# C++ multidimensional array of struct

Tags: c++, memory-management, recursion

I'm writing a program that counts all binary trees with n nodes and height k. Every node has 0 or 2 children. The program works but I wanted to add some memoization because the answer is always the same for some particular n and k.

I could create an multidimensional array of pairs but I already have my useful struct now. How could I declare and use this mem variable. I didn't find a good answer on this. I understand pointers but I would prefer a method without memory management.

This is an exercise from the USACO training program btw.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct state {
    int down, half;
    state(int d, int h) : down(d), half(h) {}
    int valid() {
        return down != -1 && half != -1;
    }
};

state mem[200][100];

state cnt(int n, int k)
{
    if (mem[n][k].valid())
        return mem[n][k];
    if (n == 1)
        return state(k == 1, k != 1);
    if (n > pow(2, k) - 1)
        return state(-1, -1);

    state total(0, 0);
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        state left = cnt(i, k - 1);
        state right = cnt(n - i - 1, k - 1);

        if (left.valid() && right.valid()) {
            total.down += left.down * right.down +
                          left.down * right.half +
                          left.half * right.down;
            total.half += left.half * right.half;
        }
    }

    return mem[n][k] = state(total.down % 9901, total.half % 9901);
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout ("nocows.out");
    ifstream fin ("nocows.in");

    int n, k;
    fin >> n >> k;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j <= k; ++j)
            mem[i][j] = state(-1, -1);

    cout << cnt(n, k).down << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `vector` of vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<state> > mem;
```

You can dynamically add to it and needn't worry about size (although if you roughly know the size, you can pre-allocate it to avoid resizing), and also memory clean-up is automatic - when the vector goes out of scope, its components will also be deleted.

Your code doesn't work because you don't have a default constructor for `state`.

The thing is, when you write `state mem[200][100];` the compiler will try to create 100*200 `state` objects, but it can't. To make this work, you'd need a default constructor in `state`:

```
struct state {
    state() : down(0), half(0) {}  //default constructor
    int down, half;
    state(int d, int h) : down(d), half(h) {}
    int valid() {
        return down != -1 && half != -1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction. This is what I needed but can you or someone else explain why the array declaration doesn't work?